# C++ property template for classes without standard constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, properties

I want to implement a C++ equivalent of C#'s properties that does not use C Macros at all. I created a template, that basically sets or retrieves an internal value in a fancier way that `get()` and `set()`. In the constructor there are also two parameters of type `std::function` where I can override the default getter and setter methods.

```
template<typename T>
class Property
{
public:

  Property(T initialValue, std::function<void(T&)> setter, std::function<T&()> getter)
  {
    Value = initialValue;
    Setter = setter;
    Getter = getter;
  }

  ~Property()
  {
  }

  void operator =(T value)
  {
    if(Setter == nullptr)
    {
      Set(value);
    }
    else
    {
      Setter(value);
    }
  }

  T& operator ()()
  {
    if(Getter == nullptr)
    {
      return Get();
    }
    else
    {
      return Getter();
    }
  }

  void Set(T& value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }

  T& Get()
  {
    return Value;
  }

private:

  T Value;

  std::function<void(T&)> Setter = nullptr;
  std::function<T&()> Getter = nullptr;

}
```

The following code snippet shows the definition of a `Property` object of type `int`. (Getter and setter are overridden by lambda expressions.)

```
Property<int> prop = Property<int>(0,

  [&](int& val)
  {
    // some code inside the overridden setter

    prop.Set(val);
  },

  [&]() -> int&
  {
    // some code inside the overridden getter

    return prop.Get();
  });
```

Getter and setter are called in the following way:

```
int foo = prop();

prop = foo;
```

I thought everything will work fine and it did. It did until I tried to pass a class as template type, that did not contain a standard constructor. I know, that the declaration `T Value;` causes the problem but I can't figure out any alternatives or workarounds.

Maybe, you have an idea how to make the concept work for primitive types, classes and classes without a standard constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this class is a bad idea.

All those `std::function`s will probably add a reasonable overhead (in both performance and memory).

---

That said, here's the answer:

Not specifying `Value` in the member initializer list of the constructor of `Property` causes `Value` to be default-initialized (and *then* assigned a value).

The solutuion is to initialize it in the member initializer list, instead of assigning to it in the constructor body:

```
Property(T initialValue, std::function<void(T&)> setter, std::function<T&()> getter)
    : Value(initialValue)
{
    Setter = setter;
    Getter = getter;
}
```

It's a good idea to do the same thing for `Setter` and `Getter` too.

---

Also, `Get` and `operator()` must not return non-`const` references (return by value or by a `const` reference instead). Returning a non-const reference here allows user to bypass the specified setter and change the value directly. Additionally, you should make `Get` and `operator()` `const`.

`operator=`, `Set`, and `std::function<...> Setter` should take the new value by a `const` reference.

You should pass a reference to `T Value` to `Setter` and a `const` reference to it to `Getter` as a parameter, rather than capturing references to the property in the lambdas. Capturing the reference makes your class break if it's moved.

`Getter` should return by value (to allow it to return a modified `Value`), or return `void` (if its sole purpose is to call a function when the value is returned, without being able to modify what's returned).

Comment: Seconding the overhead of `std::function`, the control block for `std::function` is huge. If you allocate a couple of those for every property of a class and then fill a vector with instances of that class you will have a bad time. I once tried to make a class that instead of methods had a bunch of members that were basically `std::function` and the constructor would assign lambdas to them to make them have the logic i wanted so they worked like actual methods. While it worked it was on the scale of x5-15 times slower on all operations compared to the class if implemented like a sane person.