# How to initialize a const reference member to another member (std vector) in C++ initializer list

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list, const-reference

I did the following as a cheap way to allow read-only access to a member container `_numbers` via `numbers`:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() : _numbers({}), numbers(_numbers) {
    // some code that populates `numbers` via `numbers.push_back(...)`
}

private:
    std::vector<int> _numbers;
public:
    const std::vector<int>& numbers;
}
```

However, doing so I see that `numbers` is empty, while in other cases it will contain the same elements as `_numbers`.

To be more precise, it seems to be undefined behavior.
In my real example (of which this a simplified version) I have multiple reference-container pairs with this scheme, where the populated data is visible in the const-reference member for *some* pairs, and for some it is not.

Any idea whats wrong with this? Any help is deeply appreciated.

**EDIT** Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo2 {
public:
     const int max1;
     const int center1;

    Foo2(const int max1_);
private:
    std::vector<int> _numbers1, _numbers2;

public:
    const std::vector<int>& numbers1, numbers2;
};

Foo2::Foo2(const int max1_)
    : max1(max1_), center1(max1_/2),
      _numbers1({}), _numbers2({}),
      numbers1(_numbers1),
      numbers2(_numbers2)
{
    cout << max1 << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<center1; i++) {
        _numbers1.push_back(i);
        cout << "A: " << i << endl;
    }
    for (int i=center1; i<max1; i++) {
        _numbers2.push_back(i);
        cout << "B: " << i << endl;
    }

    for (int i: numbers1) {
        cout << "A: " << i << endl;
    }
    for (int i: numbers2) {
        cout << "B: " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

which gives the following Output when initializing `Foo2 f(8)`:

```
8
A: 0
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
B: 4
B: 5
B: 6
B: 7
A: 0
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
```

i.e. `numbers2` does not see the contents of `_numbers2` while for `numbers1` it seems to work.

Comment: I can't reproduce any problems. Could you provide example code where something unexpected happens?

Comment: It might take a while because the real code is quite complex, but I'll try...

Comment: Some problems I can think of are copying/moving. You should provide copy/move constructor and assignment operators. problems like this: https://godbolt.org/z/fWhaTzsq7

Comment: Note references cannot be reseated, so this makes `Foo` hard to assign. If this is an issue, I'd use a getter that returns a `const` reference. Any decent compiler will optimize that down to nothing or next-to-nothing.

Comment: @StefanRiedel Thanks, but I guess the problem is not copy/move, because I print out `numbers` immediately after populating `_numbers` already inside the constructor and see differences

Comment: Sounds weird, but I agree with @user4581301, you should just go the common way and provide a method returning a const reference `const std::vector<int>& numbers() const {return _range;}`. Anyway I'm interested in the actual problem here.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to avoid the method-approach because it makes my code look cleaner without the calling brackets, as I need to iterate over these numbers very often.

Comment: It might take while because the problem appears to be non-deterministic, so I have to simplify my original while still seeing the problem.

Comment: Well that's a quite small "inconvenience". I would totally go for the method. And your code is probably not well designed if you have a lot of code sections where you iterate over those numbers. But that's just speculating.

Comment: Ok. I can see the problem with the brackets everywhere. How about overloading `operator[]`? `int operator[](size_t index) { return _numbers[index]; }`? Now you can `fooinstannce[42]` and pass on exposing the `vector` at all.

Comment: @user4581301 actually not seeing any problem with those brackets. `for(auto i : myFoo.range()) {...}` looks totally fine. And depending on the actual class and the actual vector is an operator[] quite unusual. Like a `Car` class having a member `vector<Tire> _tires`. I wouldn't want to access those tires with `myCar[3]`...

Comment: Depends on what you're doing and how you do it. Your pitch is clean, but `myFoo.numbers()[42]` looks clunky as hell. Only marginally worse than `myFoo.numbers[42]`, mind you. `myFoo[42]` is pretty slick and the user has no clude you even have a vector in there. Go to the next stp and wrap `vector`'s iterator interface, at least the `const` one and you get `for(auto i : myFoo)`. And if down the road the `vector` is replaced with a `map` for a sparse array no one is the wiser.

Comment: @StefanRiedel Now that I see your comment edit, I agree `car[3]` would be stupid. I wouldn't go down either route unless `Foo` is nothing but a container class. If it has more meaning than data, I'd expose none (or as close as possible) of its internals and expose functions that operate on the `Foo` and get a result rather than getting data from the `Foo` and operating on the data outside the `Foo` to get the result. `car.inflate_tire(3)` instead of `car.tire[3].inflate()`.

Comment: You could also implement something like C# properties. Like [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338030/c-property-template-for-classes-without-standard-constructor) (there are better ones, I just didn't find them quickly). But that is a lot of bloat just to get rid of those 2 brackets...

Comment: @StefanRiedel I've added a working minimal example now.

Comment: *"minimal working example"* Nope, it's not one. `error: 'vector' does not name a type`, etc.

Comment: If it seems like we're being unnecessarily picky, it's because every change we make to your example is an opportunity to insert a new bug (and give useless answers based on that bug) or accidentally fix the problem (and give no answers).

Comment: No it's fine, I've added the `std::` prefixes ;)

Comment: Next time, please also add the headers.

Comment: Actually it was the lack of `#include <vector>` that really got you. I'll tolerate a `using namespace std;` in a toy example.

Comment: `error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope` — You try to compile your code before posting it, do you? See [mcve] for why we ask for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const vector<int>& numbers1, numbers2;` — Here, only the first variable is a reference. You need `&` before the second variable to make it a reference as well. Then the code should work.

But I have to say that **what you're doing is a really bad idea**. You're paying for a convenient syntax with memory overhead, non-assignability, and possibly speed overhead.

Use getters instead: `const vector<int>& numbers1() const {return _numbers1;}`. Yes, you will have to type the extra `()` every time.

Comment: *facepalm*, thanks very much, I knew this for pointers but never stepped into this trap for references.

Comment: Thanks for Your further comments, can You explain why my approach has *memory*-overhead against the getter-approach (assuming that `numbers1` is accessed at least once)?

Comment: @flonk In practice, references have the same size as pointers. So (assuming 64-bit platform) you're wasting 8 bytes per reference per `class Foo` instance. I've never seen a compiler optimizing away a class member reference. (Unlike function-local references.)

Comment: Thanks, so what You say is that with the getter-approach doing `Foo foo(4); for (int k: foo.numbers1()) { ... }`, will be optimized in such a way that no reference is created at all, but becomes technically equivalent to the direct loop over the private vector `foo._numbers1`?

Comment: @flonk Yes, that should be the case. At least if you enable compiler optimizations, and if the method implementation isn't hidden in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: upvoting the answer for "what you're doing is a really bad idea"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... The main cause of the problem was given by @HolyBlackCat: `numbers2` was not a reference but an independant copy.

But IMHO there is a more fundamental problem. With:

```
public:
    const std::vector<int>& numbers;
```

You **promise** the compiler, that once initialized, the vector referenced by `numbers` **will no longer change**. Which is a lie, because the underlying vector changes...

Lying to the compiler is a sure path to UB: it will work sometimes, and will suddenly break because the compiler is free to change its actual code so that no changes to `_member` will be reflected in `members`.

Possible fixes:

- use `std::vector<int>& numbers = _numbers;` (no `const`). This one will be fine, but you loose the ability to present a read only reference
- get a fully initialized reference when you need it through a getter (i.e. a method):

  ```
    const std::vector& numbers() {
        return _numbers;
   }
  ```

  Again it is fine, provided `_number` no longer changes after complete initialization of `Foo`
- use a dedicated object, implicitely convertible to a vector that will be fully initialized before being used:

  ```
    struct Bar {
        std::vector<int>_numbers;

        Bar(bool first) : Bar(0, first) {};
        Bar(int max, bool first) {
            cout << max << endl;
            int center = max / 2;

            if (first) {
                for (int i = 0; i < center; i++) {
                    _numbers.push_back(i);
                    cout << "A: " << i << endl;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int i = center; i < max; i++) {
                    _numbers.push_back(i);
                    cout << "B: " << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }

        operator const std::vector<int>& () {
            return _numbers;
        }
    };
    struct Foo2 {
    public:
        const int max1;
        const int center1;

        Foo2();
        Foo2(const int max1_);
    private:
        Bar _numbers1, _numbers2;

    public:
        const std::vector<int>& numbers1, &numbers2;
    };
  ```